# Netty Flash XmlSocket Message Receiving Error

Tags: flash, netty, xmlsocket

I am creating my own flash game server in netty. I'm using flash policy server in the port 843 and game server port in the 8080... Also, I'm using zerodelimeter for framer; however, when i receiving messages on the flash client, i got two messages instead of one message. First message is the real message that i should get; however, the second one is the empty message. How can i avoid the second message receiving in the netty side?

Thanks,

In the below, you can look at the my ChannelPipelineFactory...

```
    public class SocketServerPipelineFactory implements ChannelPipelineFactory {

    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
        PlayerController controller = PlayerController.createPlayerController();

        ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();

        pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192,
                zeroDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));

        pipeline.addLast("handler", new SocketServerHandler(controller));

        return pipeline;
    }

    public static ChannelBuffer[] zeroDelimiter() {
        return new ChannelBuffer[] { ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(new byte[] { '\0' }),
                ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(new byte[] { '\r', '\n' }) };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using [nul delimiter](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/frame/Delimiters.html#nulDelimiter%28%29) instead of 0. Here is a [netty game server](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server) which serves flash policy file. The [policy server](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server/blob/master/jetserver/src/main/java/org/menacheri/jetserver/server/netty/FlashPolicyServer.java) is running at 843. Pasted below is the relevant spring configuration and here is the [policy file decoder](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server/blob/master/jetserver/src/main/java/org/menacheri/jetserver/handlers/netty/FlashPolicyServerDecoder.java) for reference.

```
<!-- Configure the Flash policy server. By default it runs at 843 -->
<bean id="flashPolicyServer" class="org.menacheri.jetserver.server.netty.FlashPolicyServer"
    init-method="createServerBootstrap" destroy-method="stopServer">
    <property name="pipelineFactory" ref="flashPolicyServerPipelineFactory"></property>
    <property name="gameAdminService" ref="gameAdminService"></property>
    <property name="portNumber" value="${flash.policy.port}"></property>
</bean>

<!-- All the pipeline factory beans are now defined -->
<bean id="flashPolicyServerPipelineFactory" class="org.menacheri.jetserver.server.netty.FlashPolicyServerPipelineFactory">
    <lookup-method name="getFlashPolicyServerHandler" bean="flashPolicyServerHandler"/>
    <property name="timer" ref="hashedWheelTimer"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I am afraid it didn't work.I tried the null delimiter instead of "\0"; however, flash xmlsocket object didn't trigger the message receive event. Also, i tried both null delimiter and "\0" that leads to two messages instead of one message.

Comment: Did you try out the decoder I have linked? You can actually decode and see why exactly the frame is having extra bytes. That may give a clue.